# How to save object to session in ASP.NET & access it in View

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am writing Asp.Net MVC 4 application. I want to save model object to session and then access it from another page but don't know how to do it. Is it possible? For example some code:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(EventDetails obj)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            Session["EventDetails"] = obj;
            return RedirectToAction("Index2","Home");
        }
       else return View();
```

Here Event details model code:

```
namespace ProjectMVC.Models
{
    public class EventDetails
    {
        [Required]
        public string FirstTeamName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

So I want to save EventDetails object to session and then access it in View like a normal object. Something like this:

```
@Session["EventDetails"].FirstTeamName
```

Comment: You will need to cast it to the object you are using in oreder to access it's parameters, i.e `string name = ((EventDetails)Session["EventDetails"]).FirstTeamName`

Comment: If you just want to persist the data over a single redirect, it's better practice to just use TempData instead.   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43939693/how-to-pass-tempdata-in-redirecttoaction-in-asp-net-mvc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to bind it to a ViewModel:

```
var vm = (EventDetails)Session["EventDetails"];
return View(vm);
```

In your view you simply:

```
@model EventDetails

@Model.FirstTeamName
```

Comment: Thnx , exactly what i want