# Save model in session and use it in view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session, asp.net-mvc-5

I've been looking at some of the answers on this site about saving model data to session but none seem to work for me, or most likely I am not understanding it correctly and not sure how to implement it.

This is the latest solution I've been trying.
[c# - How to save object to session in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26704800/how-to-save-object-to-session-in-asp-net)

In the Index I get an error on declaring the model telling me User doesn't exist

**Model**

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    using (DefaultConnection db = new DefaultConnection())
    {
        var model = from u in db.Users select u;

        var vm = (User)Session["User"];

        return View(vm);
    }
}
```

**View**

```
@model User

@Model.Username
```

Comment: Did you set something to session already ?

Comment: Nope, I made a fresh application just to test out setting model to session

Comment: Then you need to set it first. See my answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to save object to session in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26704800/how-to-save-object-to-session-in-asp-net)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not quite sure what you are trying to achieve here. But i can see some problems in your code

```
var vm = (User)Session["User"];
```

You are trying to access a session variable with key `User` and trying to cast it to a `User` instance. That means, Before executing this code, you should be setting a valid user object to Session["User"]. If you do not do that, your casting will fail(code will crash) because Session does not have any item for the key "User"

If you haven't set it yet, Before accessing this session object, you should set a valid `User` object to session.

```
var us = new User { Id=1, Username="test"};
Session["User"] = us;
```

Later, before accessing from session item, you should always check whether it is null or not

```
User u = null;
if(Session["User"]!=null)
{
  u = Session["User"] as User;
  // you may use u now.
}
```

Also, you are querying from the `Users` table and selecting the record**s** to the variable `model`. But you are not using that anywhere in your code. I am not sure why you want to do that.

I am not sure why you are using session. If you are trying to pass data between your action method to view, there are other better solutions like using a viewmodel (preferred), ViewBag etc.

Remember Session data is available across the entire application for the current session., not just one page. Use it wisely.

Answer (score 0):

In order to save your model to the Session, you need to set the session object  first e.g.

```
using (DefaultConnection db = new DefaultConnection())
{
    var model = from u in db.Users select u;
    Session["User"] = model; //Part where you set / save into the session 
    var vm = Session["User"] as User; //Part where you retrieve into the session
    return View(vm);
}
```

Comment: Now how do I access the values of vm in my view?

Answer (score 0):

```
User user = Session["User"] as User;
if ( user == null) user = new User();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access your ViewModel on the view, you can do it in many ways one way is to associate your view to a model (known as strongly typed views). You can do this in your view:

```
@model type @*Associate your view to a ViewModel, where type is your ViewModel Class*@

<h1>@Model.Name</h1> @*access the properties of your view using @Model *@
```

@model is used to associate a model to a view while @Model is used to access the associated model of a view. I suggest you read first on how ASP.NET MVC works. You may visit the [ASP.NET MVC tutorial on views](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/views/dynamic-v-strongly-typed-views)