# How to pass tempdata in RedirectToAction in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I need to pass one logout successful message in one of the views but I am not able to do so. Here is what I have.

**Not Working Solution:**

```
 //LogController:
  public ActionResult Logoff()
  {
      DoLogOff();
      TempData["Message"] = "Success";
      return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
  }

  // HomeController
  public ActionResult Index()
  {
      return View();
  }
```

**Index CSHTML File:**

```
@Html.Partial("../Home/DisplayPreview")
```

**DisplayPreview CSHTML File:**

```
   @TempData["Message"]
```

**Working Solution**

```
public ActionResult Logoff()
{
     DoLogOff();
     return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", new { message = "Logout Successful!" });
}

public ActionResult Index(string message)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(message))
        TempData["Message"] = message;
    return View();
}
```

**Index CSHTML File:**

```
   @TempData["Message"]
```

But I want something like my first solution.

Comment: Did you mix up the "working" and "not working" solutions? Because what you claim is "not working" is the only way it *will* work, while what you claim as "working", definitely will not work.

Comment: No, kindly give one more glance. They are in different controllers.

Comment: and why a negative vote?

Comment: Not sure. That downvote didn't come from me. Anyways, what's the problem with the first method? What is not working about it?

Comment: I am not able to see the message in my view. But when I follow the second solution it woks fine

Comment: There should be no problem there unless your routing or something is causing a further redirect. `TempData` will only survive a single request.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144075/discussion-between-unbreakable-and-chris-pratt).

Comment: You already found a working solution. Why care about `TempData`? Everything that depends on ASP.NET Sessions (and as a consequence on server side state) should be avoided.

Answer (score 2):

In the controller;

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewBag.Message = TempData["Message"];
    return View();
}
public ActionResult Logoff()
{
    DoLogOff();
    TempData["Message"] = "Success";
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```

Then you can use it in view like;

```
@ViewBag.Message
```

Comment: Debugging on local host, temp data is cleared with redirecttoaction call

Answer (score 0):

See if this works:

```
public ActionResult Logoff()
{
    DoLogOff();
    ControllerContext.Controller.TempData["Message"] = "Success";
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't show what DoLogOff() does, my guess is that you are abandoning the session, which means any data stored in session (like TempData) is lost.  A new session does not get generated until the next page refresh, so it doesn't work.

What you might try is simply passing a flag to your Index view that will show the logged off message if it's present.  I would NOT use the string message, like you show in your "working" example, because this can be coopted by attackers to redirect people to malicious sites.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I just now saw the code. I am calling `Session.abandon` and `Session.Clear` in my DolLogoff(). So instead of string you want me to pass a bool variable as parameter in index view?

Comment: @Unbreakable - that's one possibility, there are a number of other ways to do this, this is just an example.  You don't want to pass a string because someone could insert javascript into it that would do nasty things.

Comment: If you get some time can you put a small code snippet of what I should do.

Comment: `return RedirectToAction(action, homeController, new { showMes = "true" });` How to pass bool from here?

Answer (score 0):

hi i want to share my version

```
    public ActionResult List(string success,string error)
    {
            TempData["success"] = success;
            TempData["error"] = error;

      return View();
    }
     
    
    public ActionResult Add()
    {
     return RedirectToAction("List",new
       {
         error = "not added",
         success = "added"
       });
    }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).